# Spring Security Kerberos Extension Gradle Build issue

Tags: spring, security, build, gradle, kerberos

I'm trying to add the spring security kerberos extension(http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/) to my project by following their example gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-kerberos-core:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories {
    maven {
         url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
  }
```

}

and I keep getting the following error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.springframework.security:spring-security-kerberos-core:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm confused, am I doing something completely wrong, or is the kerberos extension documentation completely off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a simple typo. Try this (note 'org.springframework.security.**kerberos**' as validated by [this link](http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/security/kerberos/spring-security-kerberos-core/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/)):

**Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
     compile 'org.springframework.security.kerberos:spring-security-kerberos-core:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

task go () << {
   println "go"
}
```

**Maven**:

```
  ...
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
```

The method behind this answer was to point a browser to the top-level repo URL and manually crawl through the site. This is a successful trouble-shooting strategy for many different repos.

Comment: Excellent answer! This not only did it, but also taught me how to resolve future errors like this myself - crucial skill for someone new to the java world. Many thanks, @Michael Easter